# Plugin WooCart Pro in avada theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, responsive-design, themes

Good time.

I have a problem using the Plugin `WooCart Pro` in the `avada` theme of wordpress. When I active WooCart pro plugin website in responsive mode, the screen gets white. The website gets corrupted.. Just in responsive.

Do you know what the problem is?

[image]

Comment: Please specify all versions that you're using.

Comment: Thanks, wordpress: 4.7.1 , WooCommerce WooCart Pro : 2.3.0 @kashesandr

Comment: Avada Theme: 5.0.1 @kashesandr

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the versions are not compatible.

See details here in the right section https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-cart-woocart-pro/7992078

You're using wordpress v4.7.1 that is not in the list below:
[image]

Hope this helps.